# Merging two image from different imageView in a single image in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

i want to add two images from diffent imageview to give them 3d look such that both images overlap one another and when user show the image its shows both images and when user move their iphone by sides it show one image (only one image displayed and anothers be disappear) like a hologram.

Please help me someone its very important for me.
thank you......!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to show the images like hologram and then show only one, a possible way would be:

- Add both image to same rect initially adding as subViews and set transparency(alpha) to both images to be 0.5.
- as user move the phone show the desired image by setting its alpha to 1.0 and bringing that subview to front.

It may help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, its really helpful . Can i save this image because both images are on different image view?? If yes, tell me how ??

Comment: Is there a requirement fot you to save the overlapped image? Can you be more specific with your requirement.

Comment: To save the overlapped image you can take the screen shot of view. Are you adding these image views as a subView to a view? If yes then take the screen shot of view. You can search the code to take screenshot of a view and save as image.

Answer (score 2):

try this code for merge two image

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(firstImage.size);
[firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
[secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

```
+ (UIImage*)mergeImage:(UIImage*)first withImage:(UIImage*)second
{
 // get size of the first image
 CGImageRef firstImageRef = first.CGImage;
 CGFloat firstWidth = CGImageGetWidth(firstImageRef);
 CGFloat firstHeight = CGImageGetHeight(firstImageRef);

 // get size of the second image
 CGImageRef secondImageRef = second.CGImage;
 CGFloat secondWidth = CGImageGetWidth(secondImageRef);
 CGFloat secondHeight = CGImageGetHeight(secondImageRef);

 // build merged size
 CGSize mergedSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstWidth, secondWidth), MAX(firstHeight, secondHeight));

 // capture image context ref
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mergedSize);

 //Draw images onto the context
 [first drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, firstWidth, firstHeight)];
 [second drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, secondWidth, secondHeight)]; 

 // assign context to new UIImage
 UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

 // end context
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 return newImage;
}
```

Or try this [link](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1681).